# How to create 10,000 random coordinates in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I've been set a project where I have to generate 10,000 random coordinates (x,y), using the random module in python and then output them all. The coordinates HAVE to be decimal numbers between 0 and 2. I've had a look around on the internet but I can't seem to find anything that is helping me. Can anyone on here help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#real-valued-distributions) module within a list comprehension to generate a list of random coordinate tuples:

```
import random

coords = [(random.random()*2.0, random.random()*2.0) for _ in range(10000)]
```

This will give you 10,000 tuples (x, y), where x and y are random floating point numbers greater than or equal to 0 and less than 2.

Answer (score 9):

Or use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

coords = np.random.rand(10000, 2) * 2
```

Comment: This is probably more performant than using `random`.

Comment: @gil.fernandes: Quite a lot faster, [it turns out](https://ideone.com/ZJB1vt).

Comment: Also having the output as a numpy array is better for further processing than having a list of tuples.